# VF: On Click not working

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller

It appears I have something wrong in my syntax for the output panels but I can't figure out what it is. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? The page doesn't rerender when I click the account name.

The problem code starts at ActionSupport.

```
    <apex:page controller="LicensingGridController" sidebar="false">

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!TheHubs}" var="Hub">
            <apex:column value="{!Hub.Name}" />
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Licenses</apex:facet>
                <ul>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Hub.Licenses__r}" var="Lic">
                        <li><apex:outputField value="{!Lic.Name}" /></li>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </ul>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Accounts</apex:facet>
                <ul>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Hub.Account_Counselors__r}" var="Counselor">
                        <apex:outputpanel id="Accounts">
                            <li><apex:outputLabel value="{!Counselor.Account__r.Name}" / ></li>
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!fetchOEs}" rerender="pbOEs">
                                    <apex:param name="SelectedAcc" assignTo="{!SelectedAccid}" value="{!Counselor.Account__c}"/>
                                    <apex:param name="AccRendered" assignTo="{!AccRendered}" value="TRUE"/>
                                </apex:actionSupport>
                            </apex:outputPanel>

                    </apex:repeat>

                </ul>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="OE Dates">
                 <apex:outputpanel id="pbOEs" >
                    <apex:repeat value="{!OpenEnrollments}" var="OE" rendered="{!AccRendered}">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!OE.Start_Date__c}"/>
                    </apex:repeat>
                 </apex:outputpanel>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Here is my controller code if needed for reference:

```
 public class LicensingGridController {

    public String selectedAccId {get; set;}
    public Boolean AccRendered {get; set;}

    public LicensingGridController(){
        AccRendered = FALSE;
    }
    //
    public List<BCS__c> getTheHubs() {
        List<BCS__c> hubs = [Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,
                             (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                              FROM Account_Counselors__r),
                             (Select Name 
                              FROM Licenses__r)
                             FROM BCS__c
                             WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE];
        return hubs;
    }

    public list<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> getOpenEnrollments(){
        AccRendered = TRUE;
        List<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> OEs = [Select Account__c,Name,OE_Type__c,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c
                                          FROM OE_Rollover_Spans__c];
        return OEs;
    }

    public list<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> fetchOEs(){
        AccRendered = TRUE;
        List<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> OEs = [Select Account__c,Name,OE_Type__c,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c
                                          FROM OE_Rollover_Spans__c
                                          WHERE Account__c = :selectedAccId];
        return OEs;
    }

}
```

Bonus points: I can't get the fetchOEs to work in the apex:repeat for the second output panel called pbOEs. Can anyone tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: can you make the "AccRendered" true in the "fetchOEs()" method. When you rerender the outputpanel with id="pbOEs", it again check for the "AccRendered" which is not set to true.

Comment: can you update the apex in question with changes you made?

Comment: Controller code has been updated in original post.

Comment: did you check the debugs to see the method is executed or not and what value of boolean "AccRendered" you are getting on page?

Comment: I have the Developer Console logging set to FINEST for APEX and Visualforce. No logs are generated when I click on the label. I have clicked all over and around the label and can't get anything to respond.

Comment: Can you please check the browser console and see if you are getting any JavaScript error?

Comment: An error was generated.
http://screencast.com/t/6mZmYrF7

Comment: I found one error on my own, but it still didn't fix issue.
<apex:param...... I didn't have the value enclosed in {}
I have updated code in original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boolean  variable `AccRendered` is set to false in the constructor. Make `AccRendered` true in `fetchOEs()` method so it will get displayed.

Comment: I made that change (can't believe I didn't notice that) but it still doesn't respond to me clicking the name.

Comment: can you look at the comments on the first post. I still can't get this to render.

Answer (score 1):

You can run into trouble if you put a `rendered=` on an outputPanel when the initial condition evaluates to false as the DOM `<div>` is never initially generated so the AJAX rerender logic has nothing to work with

```
 <apex:outputpanel id="pbOEs" rendered="{!AccRendered}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!OpenEnrollments}" var="OE">
        <apex:outputField value="{!OE.Start_Date__c}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
 </apex:outputpanel>
```

Better is

```
 <apex:outputpanel id="pbOEs" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!OpenEnrollments}" var="OE" rendered="{!AccRendered}">
        <apex:outputField value="{!OE.Start_Date__c}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
 </apex:outputpanel>
```

There is a [famous blog post on this topic](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html) by the inestimable Bob Buzzard

Comment: I have updated the visualforce page code in original post with your suggestion. Still no go.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out after all the help from the peeps on this post.

I needed to add Apex:form to the visualforce page and my controller needed a change in that my fetchOEs needed to be changed to pagereference.

Working Controller Code:

```
public class LicensingGridController {

    public Id selectedAccId {get; set;}
    public Boolean AccRendered {get; set;}

    public LicensingGridController(){
        AccRendered = FALSE;
    }
    //
    public List<BCS__c> getTheHubs() {
        List<BCS__c> hubs = [Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,
                             (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                              FROM Account_Counselors__r),
                             (Select Name 
                              FROM Licenses__r)
                             FROM BCS__c
                             WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE];
        return hubs;
    }

    public list<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> getOpenEnrollments(){
        List<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> OEs = [Select Account__c,Account__r.Name,Name,OE_Type__c,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c
                                          FROM OE_Rollover_Spans__c
                                          WHERE Account__c = :selectedAccId];
        return OEs;
    }

    public PageReference fetchOEs(){
        AccRendered = TRUE;

        return null;

    }

}
```

Working VISUalForce page:

```
<apex:page controller="LicensingGridController" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!TheHubs}" var="Hub">
                <apex:column value="{!Hub.Name}" />
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Licenses</apex:facet>
                    <ul>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!Hub.Licenses__r}" var="Lic">
                            <li><apex:outputField value="{!Lic.Name}" /></li>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </ul>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Accounts</apex:facet>
                    <ul>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!Hub.Account_Counselors__r}" var="Counselor">
                            <apex:outputpanel id="Accounts">
                                <li><apex:outputLabel value="{!Counselor.Account__r.Name}" / ></li>
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!fetchOEs}" rerender="pbOEs">
                                        <apex:param name="SelectedAcc" assignTo="{!SelectedAccid}" value="{!Counselor.Account__c}"/>
                                        <apex:param name="AccRendered" assignTo="{!AccRendered}" value="TRUE"/>
                                    </apex:actionSupport>
                                </apex:outputPanel>

                        </apex:repeat>

                    </ul>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="OE Dates">
                    <apex:outputpanel id="pbOEs" >
                        <apex:repeat value="{!OpenEnrollments}" var="OE" rendered="{!AccRendered}">
                            <li><apex:outputField value="{!OE.Account__r.Name}" /> <apex:outputField value="{!OE.Start_Date__c}" /></li>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```